# Maximize a function that involves summation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

**I want to maximize this function using `fminbnd` in MATLAB.**
[image]

I am not able to correctly define the function in MATLAB. How can I create a loop for `i` to define the function accordingly and finally apply `fminbnd`?. Here's my code (*which is actually wrong*):

```
k = 0.1;    
L = sum(k - (i/n)) + sum(((i/n) - k)*log(k - (i/n))) + k;

fminbnd(-L, [], []);
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things concerning your problem.

**First**: the thing with the loop

MATLAB is great at vectorizing stuff. The command `sum` adds-up a vector, so you need to create the vector `i = 1:n` (from `1` to `n`... spaced by 1) yourself:

```matlab
n = 10; % maximum in sum
i = 1:n; % line-space => use MATLAB's vetorization
in = i/n; % put this in a new variable for the sake of conciseness

k = 10; % some random value
L = sum( (k - in) + (in - k).*log(k - in) + k )
```

the output is:

> ```
> L = 
>    -17.7921
> ```

**Second:** the thing with optimizing a function

Handing over functions in MATLAB can be done with [function handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html). Essentially, this is an object pointing to a function. In your case, we in fact need an *anonymous function handle*:

```matlab
L = @(k) sum( (k - in) + (in - k).*log(k - in) + k )
```

The variable `in` is "frozen". For the *anonymous* function handle it is as if `in` was hard coded. The `@` indicates a function handle and the followed `(k)` denotes that the variable `k` should be considered as the first input of this new function (this is why it is an *anonymous* function handle. The variable `k` becomes and anonym input).
So you could now call

```matlab
L(10)
```

and would obtain

> ```
> L = 
>    -17.7921
> ```

as before.

Now the optimization function can use this (note that you need to include the minus in the function handle, so we just wrap it in a new one:)

```matlab
fnc = @(k) -L(k)

lb = 1+10-9; % lower bound
ub = 100; % upper bound
[k_opt,fval] = fminbnd(fnc ,lb,ub)
```

> ```
> k_opt = 
>    3.2835
> fval = 
>    -32.5310
> ```

Be aware that your function becomes complex for values `k <= 1`, which is why I have restricted the minimum bound here to larger values.